# Suggestions for carousel or related for <div> click and animate interaction

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, horizontal-scrolling

After spending yesterday afternoon looking through SO and online, and not quite finding what I think I need, I wanted to ask the community for suggestions. I have a specific interaction I'm trying to prototype and am guessing there is a plugin I can use instead of start from scratch, but can't quite find it.

The interaction is a long horizontal reveal and slide. The app opens with one div visible. The user swipes or clicks to the right, and the first div slides left (but not entirely off screen) and the second div both fades in and moves into the space where the first div was. Interaction continues for as many panes as there are (for this prototype we have five levels deep). user can back in and out at will--I planned to show this by clicking the left and right sides of the visible div, as the design shows a big grey bar with an arrow fading in on each side. Moving back 'up' is reverse of going 'down'--divs fade off and the previous div slides into place.

Touch is *not* required for this demo/prototype.

As requested, here is a sketch:
[image: clarified interaction sketch.]

Comment: Added sketch. I'm not sure what you mean in #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought I would take a stab at a prototype. The dimensions are tiny because it's in jsfiddle, but you can expand the results window and change the dimensions if you wish. I only tested this in Chrome and it uses a lot of CSS3:

http://jsfiddle.net/TdAhm/4/

And here's a screenshot. Why not? I think it lines up nicely with the sketch. I'm a little bit confused about whether you actually wanted the previous div to get squished instead of just overlapped. That seems inadvisable, since the content in the div would get mangled, but it's doable.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is really gorgeous. :) The variable number of tiles is great, since that doesn't lock it in to anything. You are right that the 'higher' div just overlays the 'lower' one. The only change I would need to figure out is that the 'lower' divs slide off to the left and only the right edge is visible. Will adjust the sketch so it's a little more clear.

Comment: Hmm... not sure what role the white part now plays. Are you basically looking for spacers between each layer? I can't really say the 1st div is "sliding off" anywhere. It's already in the correct position when the 2nd comes on.

Comment: Updated sketch. Marked as answer since you answered the question I originally asked. :) Also +1 because it's so slick.

Comment: Thanks! I know it's just a prototype, but it only took a couple hours to throw together. So hopefully that's enough to get you started or simple enough that you could start from scratch.

Comment: Yes thanks I appreciate it, it is a great start. I found someone on a different team who could also help. And of course the artists change the design every day... :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like its gona be a pretty complex code

Look at chaining the .animate function make it happen

Its really hard to visualize what you're trying to make exactly... once you get femilair with using jquery i'm sure you should be able to figure this out.

use .animate, callback functions and maybe .queue

I cant provide expamples that arent better findable then first google result since its so complex

If this doesnt help you you should like Matt sayd, sketch it out and try to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give an answer, but as far as I have understood, you could take a look at

[jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html)

interacting with

[Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

I am developing something (probably) similar. Take a look at [this site](http://vloungebeach.montezuma.it/it/beach) (i am still developing).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Your layout is similar. Your interaction is similar to what I'm looking for--main difference is your content does not slide.

Comment: Not the content, but the thumbnails do. I don't think there is much difference.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that. The thumbnails kind of jump a little and then pop to the resting position. I didn't catch they were animating. :) I'm guessing you want it to be smooth?

Comment: Yeah, it is just a matter to increase the animation duration. It is a strange requirement from the client, and I agree with you, it should be smoother!